# Does Oracle Cloud Autonomous Database support MySQL without conversion to Oracle format?

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

From the Oracle documentation

> Migration is the process of copying the schema objects and data from a
> source MySQL to Autonomous Database

I undestand it here as literal copying, without any change.

On the other hand, on the chapter on migration it says(if I understood it correctly) that before using it, it must be converted to Oracle format.

I don't understand whether this conversion to Oracle format, before using the Autonomous Database is a necessary step when using it.

Comment: Those database engines are not 100% compatible (well... probably 99.9% compatible). There may be some loss during an automated conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the recommended approach (not mandatory) when performing a migration: you can resolve issues during these phases, and you can then inspect or modify objects to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Anupam. Just to make sure I got it, is it possible to use MySQL without any conversion with Autonomous Database? Because I got many queries in MySQL and I don't want to rewrite them for Oracle DB.

Comment: as said its not mandatory. You can use My SQL without any conversation  to migrate to autonomous DB. please refer https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer/19.2/rptug/migrating-third-party-databases.html#GUID-299A057B-2B51-4646-9285-043A848D2A0B document, this might be helpful.